# how can I display images using a path stored in a child table- Angular and Spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, postgresql

I'm working on a project where image url is stored in a child table(image) and the image is in a folder. I can display all images from image table.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="location">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>IMAGE</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let productImage">
        <img
          height="100"
          width="100"
          src="{{ productImage?.location }}"
          class="rounded-circle img-fluid img-thumbnail"
          alt=""
        />
      </td>
```

But when I try the following, the images are not displayed while other data is accessible through parent–child relationship. this
`product.image.name`
works okay.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="location">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Image</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">
            <img
              height="100"
              width="100"
              src="{{ product.image.location }}"
              alt="{{ product.image.name }}"
              class="rounded-circle img-fluid img-thumbnail"
              alt=""
            />
          </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the images displayed I added `image.setLocation(entity.getImage().getLocation());` in my product dto converter.